# Maven Eclipse unit test configuration

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, m2eclipse, surefire

I use Eclipse and for some of my unit tests, I need to set some JVM args for the test to work, `-Djava.library.path` in particular. I set it in my [POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) file as follows:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>-Djava.library.path=target/dll</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and it works correctly when I build with [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven). However, when I run in Eclipse (even with the Maven plug-in installed - I have everything else in my Eclipse environment working properly with maven), this JVM argument is not applied. Does anyone know why this is or how to fix this?

Comment: Just to make sure - how are you running the unit test? M2Eclipse? Right-click -> Run as test?

Comment: You might try their mailing lists:

user@m2eclipse.codehaus.org
users@maven.apache.org

Check those web sites first to see how to join the mailing lists; you have to be a member before you can post.

Comment: Robert, I'm running the test as right click -> run as test.
I'll check out the mailing list too, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running the test in Eclipse with the JUnit test runner *does not* invoke maven , even if you are using m2eclipse.

I suggest you either:

- create a maven launch configuration for the `test` goal;
- add `-Djava.library.path=target/dll` to your JVM arguments in the JUnit launch configuration.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I had done the second option. my worry was that other developers would all have to modify their configs manually - I was hoping to push that out automatically. appreciate the help.

Comment: You can share your run configurations. Run -> Run Configurations -> JUnit -> (select one) -> Common -> **Shared file**, then check into SCM.